# How to amend html code to auto maximise page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, html

I have a sharepoint online site with several sub sites within it.

On each of the pages are 9 boxes, arranged in a 3x3 pattern.  These boxes have images on them and act as a navigation grids to other pages and content.

The problem that I have with a user base of circa 20-30 people is that on some screens the grid is 3x3 and on others it is displaying as 2x6.

All machines and screens are identical and so is the software on them.

Can I amended the page code so that 3x3 always shows.  Something like maximising screen?

Comment: As a note the boxes mentioned are nothing more than images of icons with a hyperlink to other subpages on the sharepoint site

Comment: "Yes" would be the answer to your question. But if to be serious - we need more details, please, include the screenshot, type of the webpart used, page type (modern vs classic), Html and JavaScript used, etc. Otherwise it's impossible to tell what you are talking about.

Comment: I think that I have partially answered the issue by removing the menu on the right hand side.  Now all terminals are showing the 3x3 grid (images with hyperlinks to other pages in the same site).   Only issue now is that there is a larger white area on the right hand side that is vacant and I can’t add anything into it.  Seems like a margin or something.